# capacitor discharge circuit

Tags: circuit-design, analog-switch

[image]
I'm designing a capacitor discharging control circuit. Its principle is as follows:

- Voltage monitor 1 function:

  - switch, Short 2 and 3 for less than 14.85v
- Voltage monitor 2 function:

  - upper limit, Output low level when voltage higher than 14.39v
- Voltage monitor 3 function:

  - lower limit, Output low level between 11.62v-10.12v
- Why need monitor 1?

  - If voltage monitor 2 is connected under 14.39v, the output signal will stay low, which causes PMOS U1 cannot close, so it must be connected after the voltage is higher than 14.39v

-Result:

- Load is connected between 11.64v – 14.30v
  [image]

My question is:

1. I want to change the current source to 100mA and R2 to 150Ω(which can ensure the output current is 15V), but the output can not be controlled after that change.
2. The Load is must around 10kΩ， I cannot change it to other values(otherwise it will not work.)
3. Is there any other ways to control the discharge? I would like a circuit as a reference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In addition, the voltage-limiting parallel resistance of the current source in Ltspice will shunt, how to avoid this situation and create a constant voltage and constant current power supply?

Answer (score 0):

It appears VM1 (U6) is only used for the initial charge from 0 to 14.85V and seems to have no purpose other than that.

What's missing is the "system design spec" of values for the forest.
Instead, you have designed trees and branches with a question about one tree.

A spec should define all desired inputs, functions and outputs.

Voltage range, Current range, C range ESR if relevant, thresholds for charge/discharge rate (RC=T or Icc) or cycle time.

Then you can apply this to Supercaps or batteries for life testing to the OEM relevant test spec.  There may be better ways to do this.